# OpenCV WebAssembly

Tags: c++, opencv, emscripten, webassembly, cmake-gui

I try to run this tutorial, http://videocortex.io/2017/opencv-web-app/, to build and try out OpenCV WebAssembly. But I can´t get over step "The Build System" I´ve build emscripten 1.38.21, installed Python 2.7.5.3_64bit and CMAKE 3.13.2 but get an error in the end:

Did I missed something?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I run emcc -v I get some error´s also:

> WARNING:root:LLVM version appears incorrect (seeing "6.0", expected
>   "3.7") ERROR:root:Emscripten, llvm and clang versions do not match,
>   this is dangerous (1.35.0, "1.38.21", "1.38.21") ERROR:root:Make sure
>   to use the same branch in each repo, and to be up-to-date on each. See
>   http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/LLVM-Backend.html
>   INFO:root:(Emscripten: Running sanity checks) emcc (Emscripten
>   gcc/clang-like replacement + linker emulating GNU ld) 1.35.0 clang
>   version 6.0.1  (emscripten 1.38.21 : 1.38.21) Target:
>   x86_64-pc-windows-msvc Thread model: posix InstalledDir:
>   D:\Repositories\emsdk\clang\e1.38.21_64bit WARNING:root:LLVM version
>   appears incorrect (seeing "6.0", expected "3.7")
>   ERROR:root:Emscripten, llvm and clang versions do not match, this is
>   dangerous (1.35.0, "1.38.21", "1.38.21") ERROR:root:Make sure to use
>   the same branch in each repo, and to be up-to-date on each. See
>   http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/LLVM-Backend.html
>   INFO:root:(Emscripten: Running sanity checks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone has successfully compiled OpenCV to WebAssembly. You can visit the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/njor/opencvjs) and follow the steps:

1. Get the source code:

   `git clone https://github.com/ucisysarch/opencvjs.git
   cd opencvjs
   git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv
   cd opencv
   git checkout 3.1.0`
2. Install Emscripten:

   `./emsdk update
   ./emsdk install sdk-incoming-64bit --shallow
   ./emsdk activate sdk-incoming-64bit
   source ./emsdk_env.sh`
3. Build OpenCV to WebAssembly.

   `python make.py --wasm`

Comment: sir, in this example the emscripten is installed inside opencvjs/opencv ?? Please clear my doubt.

Comment: @MayankTiwari No. You have to install Emscripten before building the source code.